# mysqld failing to start, and mysql error 2002

Tags: mysql, debian, lamp

Okay, I've looked around, but I'm very confused with the problem. Please forgive me if it's something stupid. :*S I'm running 32bit Debian 6.0.6.

```
    root@debian:~# service mysql start
    Starting MySQL database server: mysqld . . . . . . . . . . . . . . failed!
```

So, the the service fails to start.

```
    root@debian:~# mysql
    ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

And this is the error given when running the command mysql. Is this error because mysqld failed to start? Or is there another reason?

I went to the directory, /var/mysqld/ and there wasn't a file named mysqld.sock. Is that the issue, or am I an idiot? hahah. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

*EDIT*: Also, it appears that logs associated with mysql, such as mysql.log and mysql.err have no value to them, they're blank. Also, I've chmod 777'd all the directories that mysql acts in. The service still continues to refuse running.

Comment: Look in the log to find out what failed.  /var/log/mysql probably. (can't remember where debian puts it)

Comment: In that directory, there aren't any files at all. Though, I'm going to  investigate to find where the file may be.

Comment: Look in /etc/my.cnf to find out where the log file path has been defined

Comment: Looking at the my.cnf file, it appears that the default location for the logs are exactly where you mentioned, /var/log/mysql/, however I have noticed that there are some .log files in the previous directory, /var/log/. The files, mysql.err, mysql.log, mysql.log.1.gz, and mysql.log.2.gz are all in this directory. I opened mysql.err and mysql.log with nano, and they are both blank files, with nothing written inside them. wtf?

Comment: @DrDeviation could you please select an answer if one of them solved your issue so that we can mark this as closed?

Answer (score 8):

Try to track down the error a bit differently. Run MySQL in the foreground.

```
mysqld_safe --log-error=/var/log/mysql.err
```

This should produce a log with some details at `/var/log/mysql.err` hopefully and add the details to your question if any in case my solution below doesn't work and someone else can help.

You may end up getting an error `mysqld_safe: command not found` and if you do, use the `locate` command to find it.

```
locate mysqld_safe
```

This will tell you where it is. For example, if it returns `/usr/bin/mysqld_safe`, run the command

```
/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --log-error=/var/log/mysql.err
```

If I had to hazard a guess, you will find an error about *pthreads*.

```
InnoDB: Error: pthread_create returned 12
```

If this is the case, the easy solution is to disable *InnoDB* for MySQL. Chances are you won't need this, so disable it in the config.

To turn off InnoDB, edit the MySQL configuration file at `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` and add this to it

```
skip-innodb
```

Now start MySQL

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Comment: Chances are you won't need InnoDB?  You're kidding, right?  Of the two basic engine options, MyISAM and InnoDB, the latter is superior in nearly every way as of MySQL 5.6.  Unless you're installing some ancient software, InnoDB is essential.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem.

The /tmp dir was not writbale, so MYSQL couldn't write some needed file.

Just do this :

```
chmod 777 /tmp
```

and restart mysql

```
/etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Comment: I also had this problem, and this solution fixed it for me. In my case, my entire `/tmp` directory had somehow been deleted. After it was recreated, I did the `chmod` and it worked.

Comment: I get the error `[FAIL] /etc/init.d/mysql: ERROR: The partition with /var/lib/mysql is too full! ... failed!`

Comment: Solved: try `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start` still the previous error mentioned in the question occurs though...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem for days, and it was my network (DHCP) along with mysql configuration (which I always experiment with).

This may help you:

- open `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`
- find `bind-address` and make sure the ip address is correct or commented out like so
  `#bind-address`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same

I've uninstalled zlib1g-dev and all went fine

Comment: What made you decide to uninstall `zlib1g-dev`? Please provide more context than "I did X or Y".